# Antedating preposition 'following'

Tags: etymology, prepositions

The *OED* has the preposition *following* from 1947. I've found this :

- *Following the order observed in the report, the first branch of study noticed is Engineering, in its two branches, military and civil.* 1826

I don't see much in between though. Are there other examples of this preposition before 1900?

Comment: On the subject of new members of closed classes, did you ever publish your 2013 paper?

Comment: Not in a peer reviewed fashion. Reynolds, Brett and Geoffrey K. Pullum (2013) New members of 'closed classes' in English. Unpublished paper, University of Edinburgh. Online at http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/~gpullum/ClosedClasses.pdf (retrieved 17 May 2021).

Comment: Thank you. Appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

It’s at least debatable whether *following* in the 1826 example is a preposition. The OED’s 1947 citation is:

> The prologue was written by the company following an incident
>   witnessed by them during anti-Jewish demonstrations following the
>   hanging of two British soldiers in Palestine.

In that example, *following* can be replaced by at least one of the three terms provided in the OED’s definition: *as a sequel to, in succession to* and *after*. Can we, equally, instead of 'Following the order observed in the report', say 'As a sequel to / in succession to / after the order observed in the report'? Possibly, but that may not give the meaning intended in the original. What the writer probably meant was 'Following the order observed in the report, the first branch of study **we notice** is Engineering . . .' If so, the way it has come out has *following* as the *-ing* form of the verb *follow*. As such it is a dangling participle, wrongly hooked up to *the first branch of study*.

Comment: Yes, the distinction between a preposition and a dangling participle is a fine one. For me this example doesn't dangle, but your mileage will vary. The question, though, remains: Are there other examples of this preposition before 1900?

Answer (score 4):

Answering your question, I can say that in your example it's not a preposition but a participle. 
(As Barrie England noticed, it's a dangling participle, which is a grammatical solecism: but the answer remains the same.)

EDIT:   It's hardly ever clear when a word, commonly used as a participle, is extended to the point of becoming a preposition; if the OED believes *following* as a preposition dates only from c1947, I would be loth to disagree.  My belief is strengthened by the fact that your apparent counterexample is in fact not a preposition at all. (Apologies if the  brevity of my answer failed to convey the meaning.)

Comment: I agree. I've been thinking on similar lines, as you will see from my own answer.

Comment: I understand and appreciate the comment, but I don't think it answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me whether that sentence uses *follow* to mean *obey*, *come after* (in time or space), *go after* or *observe*.

*Following* is used many times in Milton's *Paradise Lost* (1667)

- "not following thee, I had remained in ignorance"
- "For death, the following day, in bloody fight ..."
- "Over the vexed abyss, following the track Of Satan"
- "His bounty, following our delightful task" (this one seems closest to your quote)

If you were looking for a particular meaning of "following", please update the question to be more explicit about that.

Comment: Thank you. I agree the sentence is ambiguous. Nevertheless, it's not a particular meaning of *following* that I'm after, but rather early examples of the **preposition** *following* rather than the participle *following*.

Comment: I first read "Following our delightful task..." as a preposition, although I can see it can be read otherwise.